# How to set up unique x-server instance for each vnc login

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, x-server, realvnc

I'm trying to set up a server for analysing MEG data where it's possible for multiple users to simultaneously run unique instances of Matlab on unique X instances. We have 32 gb ram and an SSD, so I'm not too concerned about performance.

However I'm fuzzy on the details of how this might be practically achieved.

Because VNC viewer by default runs on whatever x instance is active, I'm not sure if it's possible except by running separate vnc servers on separate active X-servers simultaneously.

Would it be possible to dynamically create and remove x-servers on the basis of vnc login? Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your setup, [XRDP](http://networkstatic.net/xrdp-an-easy-remote-desktop-setup-for-your-ubuntu-servers/) might work well for you.

It creates a new session for each login, and it lets you use a more minimal desktop environment than the one you use on the server.